# How to break an import line in python?

Tags: python

There are various questions about line continuations in python e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417571/breaking-a-line-of-python-to-multiple-lines), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172448/is-it-possible-to-break-a-long-line-to-multiple-lines-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python), most pointing at the [guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

> Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically
>   using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and
>   braces, or using a hanging indent

Most of the specifics are around a long `if` statement, which can use parenthesis or implicit continuations if calling a function.

This begs the question, how should you deal with `import` statements?
Specifically, what else can I do with

```
from concurrent.futures import \
  ProcessPoolExecutor
```

Is a line continuation my only option?

Comment: how about putting parenthesis around the items. that way you can format however you like?

Comment: Short answer: No.  Research effort: [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=python+import+statement+line+continuation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), then [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

Comment: It didn't occur to me to search for *multi-line* imports. I have learnt something though

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're only importing 1 thing from the package, you should continue to do it the way that you currently are.

If you're importing multiple things, do something like this:

```
from package_name import (
    x,
    y,
    z,
)
```

Answer (score 5):

if you have :

```
from a.b.c.d.e import f
```

you can change this to :

```
from a.b.c.\
    d.e import f
```

Learnt this from a colleague of mine.