# fillna and replace based on column condition python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, fillna

i have a df with MachineType, Prod/RT, and several other columns. MachineType contains either TRUE or FALSE. need to **.fillna and .replace but in different ways for MachineType. (filling values are different for TRUE and FALSE)**

Dataframe : updatedDf

my code do above calc:

```
updatedDf['Prod/RT']=updatedDf[updatedDf['MachineType']==True]['Prod/RT'].replace(np.inf,0.021660)
updatedDf['Prod/RT']=updatedDf[updatedDf['MachineType']==True]['Prod/RT'].fillna(0.021660)


updatedDf['Prod/RT']=updatedDf[updatedDf['MachineType']==False]['Prod/RT'].replace(np.inf,0.050261)
updatedDf['Prod/RT']=updatedDf[updatedDf['MachineType']==False]['Prod/RT'].fillna(0.050261)
```

But  my code gives an unexpected output with Nan values. Is there any way to fix this error?or can't we .fillna and .replace like above way?

[image]

Comment: The question, as it is now, is missing key information, e.g. sample data, sample output. It is likely to be down-voted and got closed....

Comment: Please see: [mre]

Comment: sure i will fix it

Comment: Also see [reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: it appers you are mostly there... I'd recommend using `df.loc[mask,col] = df.loc[mask,col].fillna(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to your problem is to wrap the filling and replacing in a function and use it as parameter in pandas `.apply()`. Using you approach will require the usage of `.loc[]`.

```
updatedDf = pd.DataFrame({
    'MachineType' : np.random.choice([True, False], 10, True),
    'Prod/RT' : np.random.choice([np.nan, np.inf, random.random()], 10, True)
})

# solution 1
prod_RT_dict = {True:0.21660, False:0.050261}
def fillProd_RT(row):
    if row['Prod/RT'] != np.inf and pd.notna(row['Prod/RT']):
        return row['Prod/RT']
    else:
        return prod_RT_dict[row['MachineType']]
updatedDf['Prod/RT_2'] = updatedDf.apply(fillProd_RT, axis=1)

# solution 2
updatedDf['Prod/RT_3']=updatedDf['Prod/RT'].replace(np.inf,np.nan)
updatedDf.loc[updatedDf['MachineType']==True,'Prod/RT_3']=updatedDf\
    .loc[updatedDf['MachineType']==True,'Prod/RT_3'].fillna(0.021660)
updatedDf.loc[updatedDf['MachineType']==False,'Prod/RT_3']=updatedDf\
    .loc[updatedDf['MachineType']==False,'Prod/RT_3'].fillna(0.050261)

updatedDf
```

[image]

Comment: updatedDf\
    .loc[updatedDf['MachineType']==False,'Prod/RT_3'].fillna(0.050261) what does \ meaning after updatedDf?

Comment: `\` is a wrapper for long one line code. I added it because I didn't want to write those line in one long line. If you don't understand my explanation, read [Breaking a line of python to multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417571/breaking-a-line-of-python-to-multiple-lines)